# MPLab PORTFbits has no member called RF0

Tags: c, pic, mplab, pic32

I received my chipKit Uno32 today and I wanted to program it with MPLab X. My code is fairly simple and just toggles a Pin (one with an LED...). When compiling, it gives me these errors though:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:9:5: error: '__PORTFbits_t' has no member named 'RF0'
main.c:13:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'asm'
main.c:15:9: error: '__PORTFbits_t' has no member named 'RF0'
main.c:20:9: error: '__PORTFbits_t' has no member named 'RF0'
make[2]: *** [build/default/production/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 532ms)
```

plib.h is included and I enabled c99. When disabling c99, it compiles properly! Any ideas? I'd really like to use c99 since it features quite a ton of stuff I regularly use...

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    mPORTFSetPinsDigitalOut(PORTFbits.RF0);

    while(1){
        for(int i = 0; i < 80000000; i++){
            asm("nop");
        }
        mPORTFSetBits(PORTFbits.RF0);

        for(int i = 0; i < 80000000; i++){
            asm("nop");
        }
        mPORTFClearBits(PORTFbits.RF0);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the corresponding lines of code, too?

Comment: added the code. the for loops only work w/o c99 if i init the int before the loop

Comment: btw, the code is BS i think (functionality-wise), but the compilation problem is there...

Comment: Sounds like an include problem. What files are included in your code ?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <p32xxxx.h>
#include <plib.h>

Comment: What compiler and what version are you using ?

Comment: Also, are you sure you selected the right chip in the project ? If I'm not mistaken, your chip is a PIC32MX320F128H. The last letter 'H' is very important, it defines the number of pins for the chip. The same chip with an 'F' might not have the RF0 pin.

Comment: I think ElderBug is correct. The chip you are using probably does not have RF0. Find the exact chip header file and look for RF0 inside. If you find it - it's an include problem, if you do not find it, nothing else is to be said.

Comment: the chip is correct; compiler is XC32

Answer (score 0):

try to include your library directly instead using plib.h

your chipkit uses PIC32MX320F128 microcontroller, so make sure you select it when you create a new mplab project and when you include the right header file.

One way to verify your workspace is to right click your code where you wrote RF0, go to "navigate" and then "go to declaration". If mplab opens the header file of your micro to show you the declaration of RF0 everything works fine.

If nothing happens, maybe you missed some step.

ciao!